# PostGIS Table Indexing

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Will it improve the performance of my PostgreSQL table to have an regular index on an `ID` field, as well as a spatial index on the `GEOM` field?

I've read the PostgreSQL docs as well as the PostGIS and cannot find the answer.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the usage?

Comment: just generally...I didn't know if it could possibly have the reverse affect?

Comment: You do not need any index if your only purpose is to send the table to the printer. But, probably you want to seach the table, or join it with other tables.

Comment: Indexes don't improve the performance "generally". Any index will speed up some queries but not others; you need to figure out which queries may benefit from an additional index on the "geom" column, so there's no definite answer to your question. As a side note, SELECTS will never become slower if you add an index; the main downsides to adding indexes are increased disk space usage and INSERTS and UPDATES becoming a bit slower as well.

Comment: @cogitoergosum  "As a side note, SELECTS will never become slower if you add an index"  That isn't strictly true.  The more indexes you have, the more opportunity you have for the planner to pick the wrong one.